# Flash Media Server + Database Connection? Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, flash-media-server

Is there a **good** way to connect from Flash Media Server 2 to a Database (mysql)?

If not, where does everybody store for example their user data?

The application crashes once per day, so  thats why I need to save the important data into a database. And also to validate certain userdata, for example username/password.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "The application crashes once per day"?

Comment: Due to the heavy load of users. But thats offtopic. There must be a good way to store data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Flash to a MySQL database I'd recommend Flash remoting.  http://www.amfphp.org/